# Create a user/role in mongodb that can create DBs and manage only them

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, database

I need a user in mongo that can create new DBs and admin them only, I don't want this user to manage DBs created by others.
Is there any Built-In role to do so? or should i create a new role for this?

Thanks in Advance